# How to create bridged network interface for Xen?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization, xen, bridge

I'm trying to use Xen on an Ubuntu server for the first time and have a really basic question.

I'm following [the guide in the Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) and under the `Network Configuration->Using bridge-utils` section it says:

> In a bridged setup, it is required that we assign the IP address to the bridged interface. Configure network interfaces so that they persist after reboot:
>
> sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
>
> ```
> auto lo eth0 xenbr0
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
>   bridge_ports eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet manual
> ```
>
> Restart networking to enable xenbr0 bridge:
>
> ```
> sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup xenbr0 && sudo ifup eth0
> ```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em2
iface em2 inet static
        address 68.65.120.34
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        network 68.65.120.32
        broadcast 68.65.120.63
        gateway 68.65.120.33
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 68.65.120.33 8.8.8.8 4.4.2.2
        dns-search web-hosting.com
```

This is my attempt, which caused me to lose SSH access when I tried it:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo em2 xenbr0
iface lo inet loopback

#xen
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports em2

# The primary network interface
auto em2
iface em2 inet manual
        address 68.65.120.34
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        network 68.65.120.32
        broadcast 68.65.120.63
        gateway 68.65.120.33
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 68.65.120.33 8.8.8.8 4.4.2.2
        dns-search web-hosting.com
```

Then:

```
sudo ifdown em2 && sudo ifup xenbr0 && sudo ifup em2
```

How do I modify the contents of my configuration file to work with Xen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your first network config `em2` is configured to use the `static` method. In your second one it's set to `manual`. Using `manual`, the options you set afterwards don't get applied, hence you lost access.
- Your machine is connected physically to the network via `em2`. You want to create a bridge called `xenbr0`, so you need to set `em2` to manual (what you did), set `xenbr0` to `static` (like `em2` was before, instead of `dhcp`) and move all the options from `em2` to `xenbr0`.
- So, try this:

  ```
  # The loopback network interface
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  #xen
  auto xenbr0
  iface xenbr0 inet static
         address 68.65.120.34
         netmask 255.255.255.224
         network 68.65.120.32
         broadcast 68.65.120.63
         gateway 68.65.120.33
         # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
         dns-nameservers 68.65.120.33 8.8.8.8 4.4.2.2
         dns-search web-hosting.com
         bridge_ports em2

  # The primary network interface
  auto em2
  iface em2 inet manual
  ```
- There are some more options you could set, especially in a virtualized environment:

  ```
         bridge_stp off       # disable Spanning Tree Protocol
         bridge_waitport 0    # no delay before a port becomes available
         bridge_fd 0          # no forwarding delay
  ```